# Handle 'lambda in JSX attribute' case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tslint

There is an existing code:

```
const FooRoute: React.SFC<RouteProps> =
  ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    if (!auth.isFoo()) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/404' }} />;
    }
    if ('render' in rest) {
      return (
        <Route {...rest} render={rest.render} />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        Component
          ?
          <Route
            {...rest}
            render={
              (props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => <Component {...props} />}
          />
          : null
      );
    }
  };
```

There is an error here:

[image]

Now how does the `getComponent` function will look like in this case?

Thought about smth like:

```
const getComponent = (props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => () => (
  <Component {...props} />
)
```

Then one can simply:

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={getComponent}
/>
```

But in this case `Component` is undefined. Any clues?

---

**EDIT:** Important Note - using TypeScript. So have to pass the Component somehow down into `getComponent`.

---

**EDIT2:** the reason I've used double lambda is because it allows handling situations like this:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => (foo: string) => {
  ...
}
```

with

```
<button onClick={handleClick('bar')} ... // foo === 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `getComponent` is a lambda function which returns another lambda function but not component because of `(props) => () => ...`. Modify your `getComponent` function to receive Component from `render` function like below.

```
const getComponent = (Component: Component) => (props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => (
  <Component {...props} />
)
```

and modify this 'render' function too.

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={getComponent(Component)}
/>
```

**Note:** You are receiving component as `component` with small `c` and using it as `Component` with capital `C`.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using a TypeScript, getting: _Cannot find name 'Comonent'_ - this is the main struggle to pass it somehow down into `getComponent`.

Comment: Very nice, it solves the issue. Now just need to figure out how to pass a type of Component (a generic) to avoid using `any`.

Comment: You can use `Component` as type of component.